# Meaning of elevator stack?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

> So when the word spread that Lila Mae had been assigned the 18-deep
> elevator stack in the Fanny Briggs Memorial Building (18-deep!), a
> career-making case for any inspector, few were surprised and whatever
> ground Chancre lost among the Old Dogs of the Guild was more than
> compensated for by the goodwill generated by the raise and the new
> mother-of-pearl jackknife screwdrivers.

This is from *The Intuitionist* by Colson Whitehead. I wonder what elevator stack would mean here?

Answer (score 5):

An *18-deep elevator stack* appears to be a bank or set of 18 elevators (shafts, cars, and equipment).

> One of the **elevators** [Number Eleven] in the Fanny Briggs **stack**
> went into total freefall this afternoon. (p.35)

*Deep* in this case refers to the (horizontal) set of individual (vertical) shafts or elevators (similar to how we used "depth" for the front-to-back dimension of a table and not its height).

I have not yet found a precise definition; however, in the following examples, elevator *stack* appears to mean a *collection of shafts and cars*, i.e., a *bank*:

> **Room tip**: It is a big hotel. There is just **one elevator stack of
> 3**, so, if you get one away from the elevator, it is a long walk.
> [Brian Spencer; post at tripadvisor.com](https://www.tripadvisor.co.nz/ShowUserReviews-g32414-d125708-r257770367-DoubleTree_by_Hilton_Hotel_Fresno_Convention_Center-Fresno_California.html)

> I had one of the students put the first unit on the roof of the lab.
> It's in a cardboard box next to the **elevator stack**. [Steven Gould;
> *Exo*](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Exo/wnItBAAAQBAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=next%20to%20the%20%22elevator%20stack%22&pg=PA238&printsec=frontcover) (2014)

> Location in Elevator Bank Elevator service varies considerably from
> one building to the next, based upon your position in the **elevator
> stack**, so it's no surprise that the *floor* you're located on may
> dramatically impact the elevator waiting time. [Gregg Lorberbaum;
> *Leasing in NYC*](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Leasing_NYC/n-sj3MGRIEAC?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=next%20to%20the%20%22elevator%20stack%22&pg=PT157&printsec=frontcover) (2013)

> The wires in this **elevator stack** are run in brass armored conduit and
> *at each floor* branches are taken $20,900 off the main feeder. These
> branch circuits are protected by cut-outs located in the **elevator
> stack**. [*New York Legislative Documents, Vol. 4*](https://www.google.com/books/edition/New_York_Legislative_Documents/lFc7AQAAMAAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=by%20the%20%22elevator%20stack%22&pg=RA1-PA189&printsec=frontcover) p.189

> Mays might have been correct, though, in hypothesizing that the
> robbers replaced the paperboard on the *elevator shaft* to cover their
> tracks. If they were able to use the **elevator stack** as an exit,
> they certainly could have entered the same way. [Stephen Trampe; *The Queen of
> Lace*](https://www.google.com/books/edition/The_Queen_of_Lace/8doQHNX_k6AC?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=by%20the%20%22elevator%20stack%22&pg=PA110&printsec=frontcover) (2003)

> We circle around to the back of the **elevator stack**, where the kitchen
> is tucked safely out of view of the *elevators*. [Michael Lucas;
> *Terrapin Sky Tango*](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Terrapin_Sky_Tango/Z7cYEAAAQBAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=by%20the%20%22elevator%20stack%22&pg=PT380&printsec=frontcover) (2019)

> The resumption of any work (if granted) may not be allowed to occur
> until after any other work scheduled for any other *unit* in the
> **elevator stack** has been completed at the discretion of the General Manager where such work was previously scheduled. [Plaza South
> Association; *Contractor's Information Package*](http://plazasouthfl.com/documents/resources/forms/contractors_package.pdf) (2019)

---

I haven't made any progress as to why *stack* is used. In fact, "elevator stack" seems so uncommon that I'm curious why these authors think readers will understand the term. Perhaps *stack* is meant to convey something technically different from *bank*.

Comment: I think there is an association with the [chimney stack](https://www.sweepsmart.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2021/07/Shared-stack.jpeg). Dictionaries mention that the **stack** is the part of a chimney that is above the roofline but there is more to it than that. Many older British houses had a fireplace in every habitable room, and their chimney flues took different routes through the masonry to a common construction for strength, and to aid simple roof design. The picture shows a **stack** of chimneys arranged together, i.e. a collection, a row of chimneys.

Comment: @WeatherVane I'm seeing [chimney stack](https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/chimney_stack) as singular: "The part of a chimney that projects above a roof." I also see the plural (stacks) used for, say, four conduits grouped in one piece of masonry: [picture](https://www.google.com/search?q=chimney+stack&rlz=1C1CHBD_enUS911US911&sxsrf=APq-WBu92Qq9fWGp_3T6wZUo4LESeZtKVw:1647647401333&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&sqi=2&ved=2ahUKEwjL78jw7ND2AhUC4BoKHTTqDlQQ_AUoAXoECAIQAw&biw=1123&bih=540&dpr=1.25)

Comment: It's a single stack of several chimneys. The caption for the second picture "Pointing to walls or chimney stacks" is a generalisation, not a statement that this example is "stacks". Notice that the picture itself is labelled "stack". BTW I'm an not criticising the answer, I voted up. Why is it "a stack of elevators"? In the same way that it is "a stack of chimneys".

Comment: ... not because they are above the roofline, but because they are all together.